# Usability measures for evaluating UI

Tags: user-interface, usability

In Software Engineering book by Ian Sommerville  8 edition , more specifically in chapter 16 , the author has proposed the following usability attributes to evaluate UI :
[image]

I can't understand what is the meaning of Speed of operation and adaptability according to their given definitions. In more details , I can't understand what is the meaning of " user's work practice" and "tied to a single model of work" ?  Please someone give an easy example to understand these 2 attributes . Many thanks :)

Comment: There is a whole engineering discipline called "User Experience" (UX).  You can even get a degree in the discipline.  The answer to your question lies in the science and targeted studies that the UX team conducts to make sure your app serves its target audience the best way possible.  That is what gets you the complete picture of usability.

Comment: There's a UX StackExchange site, too:
https://ux.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

The author of your book does not think of usability in terms of the larger discipline of User Experience (UX).  The biggest problem with the text book is that it is written like a text book.  That means the English phrasing can be clumsy, reducing the book's usability.

First, to answer your specific questions:

- **Speed of Operation:** is best described as the performance of the software.  I.e. how fast is it?
- **Single model of work:** is best understood as a measure of whether the software was written to only support one way of doing something or not.

To better understand how performance affects the way the user works with the software (user's work practice), the Nielson Norman Group performed a [study](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/response-times-3-important-limits/) to determine curtain thresholds that affect the userfulness of an application.  The result provides some human factor understanding:

- Threshold of Instantaneous Response: < 0.1 seconds
- Threshold of User's flow of thought: < 1 second
- Threshold of User's attention: < 10 seconds

In short if your application responds faster than a second you won't interrupt the work that your user is doing.  Between 1 second and 10, your application will be perceived as slow, but still usable.  With no response after 10 seconds the user will assume the application is broken.  Individual thresholds may differ, but the study revealed that those thresholds are *generally* true.

The metrics used by the author of Software Engineering aren't necessarily good indicators of whether software is useful or not.  They are common problems for why something is less usable, they don't give you a picture of what is more usable.

A User Experience team uses targeted research to derive what "usable" is for your end users.  With a combination of usability surveys and monitored user testing, they determine not only the right look and feel for the app, but also the optimal steps required for a user to get their work done.

Comment: Excellent post overall but I'd correct one point as follows. The application is actually *perceived as slow* between 0.1s and 1s, but it remains *acceptable to use*. The 1s to 10s range *will* interrupt the user's flow of work, so users will experience fatigue and displeasure, and it will thus be widely regarded as unusable in industrial contexts. Beyond 10s and there is little prospect of any user maintaining constant attention to the task - they'll be looking to do a crossword or apply their makeup in parallel.

Comment: Many thanks for your response But one more question  regarding the adaptability measure. It states that how closely is the system tied to a single model of work . This means that when the system do something one way only is better ( high adaptability ) than doing it in many ways . But  why doing the same thing in many ways has a low usability ( low adaptability ) ? I think when you give many options you increase the usability ?

Comment: @AAA, I think "adaptability" is probably a question of whether the system is *unjustifiably* restrictive or specialised. For example, a common case is where systems require one-at-a-time entry, when list-style entry could have easily been provisioned to cope with both single and multiple entry.

Comment: *"This means that when the system do something one way only is better ( high adaptability than doing it in many ways"*??? Obviously, the opposite is true - for a system offering different ways of accomplishing the same task (i.e. using *mouse* or *keyboard* for the same operation), the adaptability is higher. Or think of your favorite configurable IDE which might be configured to "Emacs mode" or "Vi mode" - different ways of working = higher adaptbility.